# How to manage Managed Executor Service

Tags: multithreading, jakarta-ee, thread-safety, threadpool

I'm using Managed Executor Service to implement a process manager which will process tasks in the background upon receiving an JMS message event. Normally, there will be a small number of tasks running (maybe 10 max) but what if something happens and my application starts getting hundred of JMS message events. How do I handle such event?

My thought is to limit the number of threads if possible and save all the other messages to database and will be run when thread available. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My thought is to limit the number of threads if possible and save all the other messages to database and will be run when thread available.

The detailed answer to this question depends on which Java EE app server you choose to run on, since they all have slightly different configuration.

Any Java EE app server will allow you to configure the thread pool size of your Managed Executor Service (MES), this is the number of worker threads for your thread pool.

Say you have a 10 worker threads, and you get flooded with 100 requests all at once, the MES will keep a queue of requests that are backlogged, and the worker threads will take work off the queue whenever they finish work until the queue is empty.

Now, it's fine if work goes to the queue *sometimes* but if overall your work queue increases more quickly than your worker threads can take work off the queue, you will run into problems.  The solution to this is to increase your thread pool size otherwise the backlog will get overrun and your server will run out of memory.

> what if something happens and my application starts getting hundred of JMS message events. How do I handle such event?

If the load on your server will be so sporadic that tasks need to be saved to a database, it seems that the best approach would be to either:

1. increase thread pool size
2. have the server immediately reject incoming tasks when the task backlog queue is full
3. have clients do a blocking wait for the server task queue to be not full (I would only advise this option if client task submission is in no way connected to user experience)

Comment: I like option 3 because these are tasks will be running on the background and will notify the user when they are done. 
Option 1 would be fine but I have no idea how many JMS message events I would get.  
Option 2 would be my second choice. My app would stop calling external rest service for new task and wait until there is an available thread. 
Thank you for answering my question.

Comment: After I read option 3 again. I think option 2 is the best way to go :D